# Is it possible to get a deep copy of objects using the VersionOne Java SDK?

Tags: java, versionone

Let's say I want to calculate the cumulative estimate of my defects.  I do

```
double estimate = 0.0;
Double tEstimate = 0.0;
Collection<Defect> defects = project.getDefects(null);
for(Defect d : defects){
   tEstimate = d.getEstimate();
   if(tEstimate != null){
      estimate += tEstimate;
   }
}
```

Here each call to d.getEstimate() does a callback to the server, meaning this code runs extremely slowly.  I would like to take the one-time performance hit up front and download all the info along with the Defect object, probably including getting some information I won't use, but avoid hitting the latency of a server callback during each iteration of the loop.

Comment: if its your code on the server you can make another API. if its some one else then they have to do that. if its on another server its another jvm so no meaning to 'deep copy'. also you have not shown what getEstimate readlly does/ but by the looks of it u just need anohter api that does what u want : return a collection of defects and their nested estimates

Answer (score 2):

You are using the VersionOne Object model SDK.  It does lack robustness because of the very thing you are complaining about.  One of the inefficiencies is how it knows that you are requesting a list of assets but first gets all of the assets with a predetermined set of attributes such as AssetState and checks to see if it is dead asset.  After this, it makes another call to get the same list of assets again but with your specified attributes.  This could be remedied by applying a greedy algorithm that could grab a set a of attributes such that each member of this set is returned regardless of which attributes are requested in your .get_() method. Why? This already (sort of) happens in the Rest based VersionOne API as it stands. If the query returned all attributes, it would probably a little wasteful especially for humongous backlogs.

Anyway, the VersionOne will be deprecating the Object Model in the near future so if you plan on a lot of coding using the OM, consider this.

Here are some ways to circumvent this problem

1)  Rewrite your code to use the VersionOne APIClient SDK.  It has XML plumbing so that you will save you a lot of time writing your own. This is a little bit more verbose but it is more powerful, fast and efficient. The Object model is actually built upon the APIClient.

2)  Rewrite your code using Java and the raw VersionOne Rest API - The requires that you understand http and the VersionOne Rest API.

3) If you cannot change from the Object model, you can mix the 2 sdks.  When you need to read large amounts to data, just use APIClient code to manage that segment of the code. Kind of pointless when you can just learn the APIclient and use exclusively unless you have a huge investment in using the Object model and you can't change. The code gets mucky real fast. Not recommended.

Answer (score 1):

The `rest-1.v1` API endpoint exposes operations for assets, including `DeepCopy`. There is no client code that enumerates all of the operations, so you must first [explore the asset](https://community.versionone.com/Developers/Developer-Library/Recipes/Explore_the_attributes_for_an_asset_type) using the `meta.v1` API endpoint. Using the [API Client backdoor from the Object Model](http://versionone.github.io/VersionOne.SDK.Java.ObjectModel/api_client.html), you can get to the classes that will allow you to [call an operation](http://versionone.github.io/VersionOne.SDK.Java.APIClient/operations.html) once you know the name.